# Check if any index match result matches criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I need to convert the following formula to check whether **any** of the index/match results meet the criteria (are equal to M2).

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(L2,B:B,0)),0,IF(INDEX(M:M,MATCH(L2,B:B,0))=M2,1,0))
```

To be exact I need this part updated:

```
IF(INDEX(M:M,MATCH(L2,B:B,0))=M2,1,0)
```

First I check whether the value from L2 exists in column B. Let's say there are two rows for which this is true. 
I want to check whether the value in column M in any of the two results is equal to M2 and if yes, output 1, if not, output 0.

Is it possible? Would it be better to use a macro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be enough to check the existence of L2 in B:B at the same time if the position on M:M contains the value of M2.

`=IF(COUNTIFS(B:B,L2,M:M,M2)>0,1,0)`